# No indication jquery ajax call completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following ajax call

```
function update_ledger_amount(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ledgeritems/UpdateAmount",
        data: "Id=" + id + "&Amount=" + $('#ledger_edit_amount_input_' + id).val(),
        success: function (str) {
            var result = str.split('|');
            alert(str);
            if (result[0] == 'success') {
                set_display_message('Item updated', 'success');
                load_ledger_month($('#BankAccountId').val(), $('#StartDate').val());
            }
            else {
                alert('bad');
                set_display_message(result[1], 'error');
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I get no alerts on success or error.  Watching the traffic via firebug I can see the response is a simple

```
success
```

I believe the problem could have to do with the content-type of the response, it shows as text/javascript.  I'm thinking maybe I need to do something different to handle that content type.

Comment: So don't leave us hanging .. does it work when you change the content type of the response?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - damn right. However i bet this line of questioning lead to an expansion of homeboy's mind in terms of request / response lifecycle - ./headbangs - i hope they either solve it or come back

Comment: If it worked I certainly wouldn't be asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dataType` as json and send the response as json in your controller(php).. you can do that by ...`echo json_encode(array('success'=>'success'))`

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ledgeritems/UpdateAmount",
    data: "Id=" + id + "&Amount=" + $('#ledger_edit_amount_input_' + id).val(),
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (str) {
        alert(str.success);  //in mycase.. you can do your stuff here
        /*var result = str.split('|');
        alert(str);
        if (result[0] == 'success') {
            set_display_message('Item updated', 'success');
            load_ledger_month($('#BankAccountId').val(), $('#StartDate').val());
        }
        else {
            alert('bad');
            set_display_message(result[1], 'error');
        }*/
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
.....
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'success'));
```

this sends success as json and you can get that in `success` function of `ajax`

Comment: I think this is probably the best route to go.

Answer (score 0):

put a try catch block in your success handler. I guess it is failing at this line

ar result = str.split('|');

Comment: Can you atleast put an alert before that split statement to see if it reaches there?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a POST ajax not GET. The data part of the ajax should be in the form of:

```
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
type = "POST",
```

because you want to append params to the url with your request.

As of jQuery 1.8 success, error and complete are deprecated, use done, fail and allways instead.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

The syntax for a POST would be like:

```
data = {id:"something", Amount:"someval"};
```